# 'variables are undefined' when writing matrix function (matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to write a function that will calculate the dot product of two vectors. I simply want to say that the numbers included in the vector can be all reals, but I keep getting a variable is undefined error.

```
A=[m:k]; B=[k:n];
n = sym('n','real');
m = sym('m','real');
k = sym('k','real');

N = A(i,:)*B(:,j); 
dotAB = Sum(N);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with

```
A=[m:k]; B=[k:n];
```

you cannot define the m k n they wont work with syms and for dot product
it write this line instead

```
N = A(i,:).*B(:,j);
```